# Should I remove the "Run" from my TextBlocks?

Tags: windows-8, winrt-xaml, textblock

I've got some TextBlocks that look like so:

```
        <TextBlock>
                <Run Text="Prev"/>
        </TextBlock>
```

However, when I created them they didn't have the "Run" jazz. Was this something added by a tool, and if so, why? Should I remove it/what is Run's raison detre?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Textbox described in your question could also be achieved by using

```
<TextBlock Text="Prev"/>
```

`Run` is just another way of setting the text of a textbox. Is use may become more apparent when you want to format certain parts of text in a textbox e.g.

```
<TextBlock>
    <Run Text="Number: " FontStyle="Bold" />
    <Run Text="1" />
</TextBlock>
```

Which might display something like

**Number:**  1

Answer (score 1):

I have noticed that editing text in TextBlock controls in Designer view (in either VS2012 or Blend) can modify the TextBlocks by inserting Runs. Runs can be quite useful but they are overkill for the simplest solutions, and the Design-time editors do mess up the markup sometimes. As a result, I tend to edit TextBlocks in XAML only.

Comment: I only know of one way to edit XAML (other than doing it in Notepad and pasting it in, which I sometimes do, as it's easier to see everything I'm doing that way); what do you mean by editing in Designer view vs. "in XAML only"? What I do is open the *.xaml file in VS, and edit away. Is that Designer view (by mashing Shift+F7 I can see the visual representation of the XAML I'm working on) or "XAML only"?

Comment: I was referring to the two panes available in the VS2012/Blend XAML editor: the text "XAML" editor pane and the WYSIWYG "Design" pane. When editing a Textblock in WYSIWYG Design mode, I have discovered that Runs get mangled. Thus I seldom edit text in WYSIWYG mode.